# Inconsistant values on % Processor Time using performance counters

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I have the following class that monitors the system to see the total cpu used by my program and the total cpu usage of the system. The problem is that sometimes, when I make the call to GetHealthInformation method, my program % CPU is bigger than the % CPU of the system.
Here is my code:

```
    public class MonitoringManager : AbstractComponent, IMonitoringManager, IStaticComponent {
    private static PerformanceCounter totalCpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total"); 
    private static PerformanceCounter cpuCounterMyProgram = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    private static DateTime lastUpdate = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public void Load() {
        cpuCounterMyProgram.NextValue();
        totalCpuCounter.NextValue();
    }

    public  HealthInfo GetHealthInformation(){
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if((now - lastUpdate).TotalMilliseconds <1000){
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        lastUpdate = now;
        return new HealthInfo(totalCpuCounter.NextValue(), cpuCounterMyProgram.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount);

    }

}


    public class HealthInfo{

    [DataMember]
    public float CpuTotal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public float CpuMyProgram { get; set; }


    public HealthInfo(float cpuTotal, float cpuMyProgram){
        CpuTotal = cpuTotal;
        CpuMyProgram = cpuMyProgram;           
    }

    #endregion IConstructors
}
```

}

What is wrong? Why sometimes the total % CPU of the system is 0% and my program is 2% ??

Comment: Did you try with longer sleep times for `NextValue()`?

Comment: Yes I did. In fact, the method GetHealthInformation() is called when i click a button on the GUI. The sleep is only to prevent that is not called in an interval of less than one second.

Comment: Pretty classic Heisenburg case.  Your cpuCounterMyProgram will always include the cpu cycles needed to read totalCpuCounter.

Comment: Can you please explain further? Normally my code works, but sometimes I get the inconsistant values.